# heroku crashea al minuto

Tags: mysql, nodejs, api, express, heroku

subi una api creada con node a heroku pero despues de hacer el push, al minuto crashea. Con **heroku restart** se arregla pero al minuto vuelve a caer. Por el rato que funciona, funciona bien pero luego se cae. En local funciona todo perfectamente no crashea para nada.

Este es log:

`

```
2020-06-11T01:38:53.754299+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-06-11T01:38:56.434516+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-06-11T01:38:56.434532+00:00 app[web.1]: > apinodejs-mysql@1.0.0 start /app
2020-06-11T01:38:56.434532+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2020-06-11T01:38:56.434533+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-06-11T01:38:56.668979+00:00 app[web.1]: Server running on port 26016
2020-06-11T01:38:56.693489+00:00 app[web.1]: Database server running
2020-06-11T01:38:58.006902+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-06-11T01:39:55.737243+00:00 app[web.1]: events.js:282
2020-06-11T01:39:55.737261+00:00 app[web.1]: throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2020-06-11T01:39:55.737261+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2020-06-11T01:39:55.737262+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-06-11T01:39:55.737263+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.       
2020-06-11T01:39:55.737263+00:00 app[web.1]: at Protocol.end (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:112:13)
2020-06-11T01:39:55.737264+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:94:28)
2020-06-11T01:39:55.737264+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
2020-06-11T01:39:55.737265+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.emit (events.js:317:22)
2020-06-11T01:39:55.737265+00:00 app[web.1]: at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1215:12)
2020-06-11T01:39:55.737265+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
2020-06-11T01:39:55.737266+00:00 app[web.1]: Emitted 'error' event on Connection instance at:
2020-06-11T01:39:55.737269+00:00 app[web.1]: at Connection._handleProtocolError (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:423:8)
2020-06-11T01:39:55.737269+00:00 app[web.1]: at Protocol.emit (events.js:305:20)
2020-06-11T01:39:55.737269+00:00 app[web.1]: at Protocol._delegateError (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:398:10)
2020-06-11T01:39:55.737270+00:00 app[web.1]: at Protocol.end (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:116:8)
2020-06-11T01:39:55.737270+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:94:28)
2020-06-11T01:39:55.737270+00:00 app[web.1]: [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
2020-06-11T01:39:55.737270+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
2020-06-11T01:39:55.737271+00:00 app[web.1]: fatal: true,
2020-06-11T01:39:55.737271+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST'
2020-06-11T01:39:55.737271+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2020-06-11T01:39:55.744121+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-06-11T01:39:55.744477+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2020-06-11T01:39:55.745396+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! apinodejs-mysql@1.0.0 start: `node app.js`
2020-06-11T01:39:55.745555+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2020-06-11T01:39:55.745727+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-06-11T01:39:55.745872+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the apinodejs-mysql@1.0.0 start script.      
2020-06-11T01:39:55.746005+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-06-11T01:39:55.752520+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-06-11T01:39:55.752733+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-06-11T01:39:55.752866+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-06-11T01_39_55_746Z-debug.log 
2020-06-11T01:39:55.812191+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-06-11T01:39:55.847674+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

`

Comment: El log indica que tu base de datos se deconecta, en tu código no capturas ese evento, simplemente el error se eleva hasta el proceso principal y esto produce que tu app se caiga. Aparte del log de error, ¿podrías mostrar el código de tu app? En especial le parte donde te conectas a la base de datos. Saludos